# ASP.NET - Two Foreach operatos with wrong logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharepoint, foreach

I have two foreach operators where :

- 1st - Find all visible rows and inserting a data into them;
- 2nd - foreach rows from CAML query and get a data.

I need foreach **first row from query** and inset data in **first visible rows**, **foreach 2nd row from query** and insert data in **2nd visible row**....
This is my code is :

```
foreach (TableRow tr in allVisibleRows)
{
   foreach (SPListItem item in myTableCol)
   {
        destination = item["Route"].ToString();
        dateGo = item["DepartureDate"].ToString();
        dateEnd = item["ReturnDate"].ToString();
        kmInCity = item["TraveledInCity"].ToString();
        kmOutCity = item["TraveledOutCity"].ToString();

        ((TextBox)tr.Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text = destination;
        ((DateTimeControl)tr.Cells[2].Controls[0]).SelectedDate = DateTime.Parse(dateGo);
        ((DateTimeControl)tr.Cells[3].Controls[0]).SelectedDate = DateTime.Parse(dateEnd);
        ((TextBox)tr.Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text = kmInCity;
        ((TextBox)tr.Cells[5].Controls[0]).Text = kmOutCity;
    }
}
```

**Result from code is :**

[image]

How to solve this problem, thank you previously....

Comment: foreach (SPListItem item in tr.ItemArray)

Comment: Please, say this in a answer.. with more details.

Comment: Do you want to add a column to the first row or do you want to add an additional row after the first row?
Of what type is `myTbl`? And is `list.GetItems(tableQuery);` the same as this [SPList.GetItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.getitems.aspx)?

Comment: Code is correct problem is with foreach operators. I skip firs row because she is header(column names). The type of my table is Web.UI.WebControls.Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loops looks correct, the logic is wrong. You simply put all the records to all the columns. And at the end you only see the last of the records.

```
int counter = 0;

    foreach (TableRow tr in allVisibleRows)
    {
            destination = myTableCol[counter]["Route"].ToString();
            dateGo = myTableCol[counter]["DepartureDate"].ToString();
            dateEnd = myTableCol[counter]["ReturnDate"].ToString();
            kmInCity = myTableCol[counter]["TraveledInCity"].ToString();
            kmOutCity = myTableCol[counter]["TraveledOutCity"].ToString();

            ((TextBox)tr.Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text = destination;
            ((DateTimeControl)tr.Cells[2].Controls[0]).SelectedDate = DateTime.Parse(dateGo);
            ((DateTimeControl)tr.Cells[3].Controls[0]).SelectedDate = DateTime.Parse(dateEnd);
            ((TextBox)tr.Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text = kmInCity;
            ((TextBox)tr.Cells[5].Controls[0]).Text = kmOutCity;

            counter++;
    }
```

Comment: This code gives me this error : Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

Comment: You probably have more or less rows in your table than the records. Make them equal to make it work.

Comment: It's counter++, to increase the counter by one.

Comment: I have 2 rows from query, where inset equal in my code... sorry but i'm begginner

Comment: No problem mate, glad if I could've helped.